# Codeigniter + HMVC is only requesting login_lang file ... all other module's lang files are not being loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter, module, hmvc

I made a copy of a working application, made some changes to modules but at some point I noticed that language files were not being loaded.

For example, at login (myApp/login), file login_lang.php is requested, and if is not present (i renamed the file so it could not find it) error is thrown.

Other modules within the app `(myApp/dashboard)` don't even request the corresponding language file `(dashboard_lang.php)` but again, if I rename `login_lang.php` with any other name, this module will throw the `"login_lang.php file was not found"` error.

I think all modules are requesting the first file (`login_lang.php`)

I've gone thru a lot of forums, questions, etc. unsuccessfully.

Any ideas of what could it be causing this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

This is my autoload.php file contents:

----- begin of file ------

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    /* 
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------
    | AUTO-LOADER
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------
    | This file specifies which systems should be loaded by default.
    |
    | In order to keep the framework as light-weight as possible only the
    | absolute minimal resources are loaded by default. For example,
    | the database is not connected to automatically since no assumption
    | is made regarding whether you intend to use it.  This file lets
    | you globally define which systems you would like loaded with every
    | request.
    |
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Instructions
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These are the things you can load automatically:
    |
    | 1. Packages
    | 2. Libraries
    | 3. Helper files
    | 4. Custom config files
    | 5. Language files
    | 6. Models
    |
    */

    /*
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------
    |  Auto-load Packges
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Prototype: 
    |
    |  $autoload['packages'] = array(APPPATH.'third_party', '/usr/local/shared');
    |
    */

    $autoload['packages'] = array(APPPATH.'third_party');


    /*
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------
    |  Auto-load Libraries
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------
    | These are the classes located in the system/libraries folder
    | or in your application/libraries folder.
    |
    | Prototype:
    |
    |   $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'xmlrpc');
    */

    $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');


    /*
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------
    |  Auto-load Helper Files
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Prototype:
    |
    |   $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
    */

    $autoload['helper'] = array('url','html');


    /*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Config files
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['config'] = array('config1', 'config2');
|
| NOTE: This item is intended for use ONLY if you have created custom
| config files.  Otherwise, leave it blank.
|
*/

$autoload['config'] = array();


/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Language files
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['language'] = array('lang1', 'lang2');
|
| NOTE: Do not include the "_lang" part of your file.  For example
| "codeigniter_lang.php" would be referenced as array('codeigniter');
|
*/

$autoload['language'] = array();


/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Models
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['model'] = array('model1', 'model2');
|
*/

$autoload['model'] = array();


/* End of file autoload.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/autoload.php */
```

----- end of file --------

Comment: How do you expect it will load `dashboard_lang` unless if you don't load it.I think `login_lang` is loaded inside your `autoload.php` that's why all controller using it and you will get error if you rename it.

Comment: Thanks Shaiful Islam for your so short reply, As i mentioned, I made a copy of a working application that loads each lang file within its corresponding module.

Im sure I did something that is misleading this feature. I've gone thru a lot of things (undoing changes) unsuccessfully. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the language you put the module name first. You can create a language folder inside the module lets say **modules => admin => language => en**

**modules => admin => language => en => dashboard_lang.php**

```
$autoload['language'] = array('admin/dashboard');
```

**Or On Controller**

**modules => admin => language => en => dashboard_lang.php**

```
$this->lang->load('admin/dashboard', 'english');
```

**With Sub Folder**

**modules => admin => language => en => common => dashboard_lang.php**

```
$autoload['language'] = array('admin/common/dashboard');
```

**Or On Controller**

**modules => admin => language => en => common => dashboard_lang.php**

```
 $this->lang->load('admin/common/dashboard', 'english');
```